# Laravel BelongsToMany Get Category Name in Index List

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and to php.

I created my categories for my news system.

On my page where I list all my news, I have the following problem while showing the category to which the news is linked.

I'm bringing the category of my article with ID 5.

But I can't do that for other news.

How can I do this on my page where I list all my news?

Thank you to everyone in advance.

My Controller Page

```
   public function index()
    {

        $data = News::all()->sortByDesc('created_at');
        $parentcategory= News::find(5)->parent_category()->limit(1)->get();

        
        return view ('SS.haber.index',compact('data','parentcategory'));
    }
```

My Model Page

```
    public function parent_category()

    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\SS\NewsCategory', 'news_category_s');

    }
```

My Views

```
<td> @foreach ($parentcategory as $pc) {{$pc->category_name}} @endforeach </td>
```

I think the problem I'm having in this area is very simple.

I was only able to pull the category of news number 5 id.

I don't know how to print categories of other data.

If public function update ($ id) {

it would work the way I did.

But I should be able to pull the categories of all records on the index page.

Comment: What happens when you try to get parent_category for other news? Please update your question if there's any error

Comment: I don't know exactly how to get that part.

What do I have to write to the controller for this and what should I write in view? @Psycho

Comment: If you want to all news with news category? If yes then here is a solution. Make relation in News model with NewsCategory model, and use that function using with.like public function newsCategory() { return $this->belongsToMany(NewsCategory::class, 'category_id', 'id'); } –

Comment: Unfortunately, these were not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

my enlish is a liitle poor.
I guess maybe you need try to plus a with('parent_category') after all()

$data = News::all()->with('parent_category')->sortByDesc('created_at');

Comment: Thans for your answer, Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist. :(

Comment: all() makes your $data-set become collection，you can try other way get all data ：  
 $data = News::with('parent_category')->get();          
 https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads